# Issue reading integers from file using Scanner

Tags: java, arrays, file, java.util.scanner

I am having an issue reading integers from an input file using scanner. Here is the bit of code I am having trouble with:

```
        String path = sc.nextLine(); 
        
        File filename = new File(path);
        
        Scanner reader = null;
        
        reader = new Scanner(filename);
        
        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {  
           while(reader.hasNextInt()) 
           {   
               System.out.println(reader.nextLine());
               pid[i] = reader.nextInt();
               arrivaltime[i] = reader.nextInt();
               burstTime[i] = reader.nextInt();
           }      
        }
```

The input file I am using contains this information:

```
1 1 1
2 2 2
3 3 3
4 4 4
```

Using this file, I am trying to make it so that pid[] = [1,2,3,4], arrivaltime[] = [1,2,3,4] and bursttime[] = [1,2,3,4]. However, each of these arrays are instead being shown as [4,0,0,0] and I can't figure out why for the life of me. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `while(reader.hasNextInt())` this line is always asking if there's an integer still there, and there are, so your `for-loop` is never doing any iterations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:
Read the line first
Then split it!

```
int i = 0
while(reader.hasNextLine()){
   String[] line = reader.nextLine().split(" ");
   pid[i] = Integer.parseInt(line[0]);
   arrivaltime[i] = Integer.parseInt(line[1]);
   burstTime[i] = Integer.parseInt(line[2]);
   i++;
}
```

Comment: No problem, if this helped you, you could accepted it as the right answer!

Answer (score 1):

When you use `scanner.nextLine()` the scanner pointer in the file skips first line.

You can use this if you don't want to print each line or use the other solution with splitting.

```
int i = 0;
while(reader.hasNextInt()) {
    pid[i] = reader.nextInt();
    arrivaltime[i] = reader.nextInt();
    burstTime[i] = reader.nextInt();
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {

        if (reader.hasNextInt()) {
            pid[i] = reader.nextInt();
            arrivaltime[i] = reader.nextInt();
            burstTime[i] = reader.nextInt();
        }
    }
```